# Smarty / Dojo checkbox onCheck uncheck other checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dojo, smarty

I am using Dojo labels and checkboxes in one of my app inside smarty file. I want to add a certain behavior to uncheck a checkbox, if any other checkbox is checked. I also check if that checkbox is originally checked, it will uncheck the same. (I do not want to use radio button)

Here is my code for one CheckBox:

```
<input id="form.cs"
     data-dojo-type='dijit.form.CheckBox'
     type="checkbox"    
     data-dojo-props="value:'true', type:'checkbox', name:'cs', style:'vertical-align: top'"
     onChange="if(dijit.byId('form.cs"').checked)                             
                  dijit.byId('form.cs"').set('checked', false);
               else 
                  dijit.byId(' form.nl"').set('checked', false);"
/>
```

The problem with code is when i add curly braces, this is not rendered by smarty engine and throws error.

For example :

```
onChange="if(dijit.byId('form.cs"').checked) {                         
                  dijit.byId('form.cs"').set('checked', false); }
               else {
                  dijit.byId(' form.nl"').set('checked', false);"}
```

The above code snippet will create a breakdown in the smarty.

Comment: So you want the behavior of a radiobutton without using a radiobutton, may I ask why?

Comment: Introducing Radio buttons were causing some weird layout issues.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend writing your event handler in JavaScript. If you're going to write all your event handlers as attributes you're going to have a lot of problems like code validation, ... .

You could write a loop that actually loops over all checkboxes, setting the value to the opposite of the changed value (so if one checkbox becomes `true`, the other ones must become `false`).

To do this you could write a simple function like this:

```
var toggleCheckboxes = function(myNode, value) {
    query("input[type=checkbox]").forEach(function(node) {
        if (node !== myNode) {
            registry.getEnclosingWidget(node).set("value", !value, false);
        }
    });
};
```

The `dojo/query` module allows you to get a list of all nodes matching the given selector. With the `dijit/registry` module you can retrieve the actual widget behind the DOM node and then you just set the value using:

```
registry.getEnclosingWidget(node).set("value", !value, false);
```

The third parameter (set to `false`) is actually **very important**. This parameter will prevent further event invocations. If you don't put that parameter there it will actually trigger another `onChange`, causing an infinite loop.

Now the only thing you need to do is bind an `onChange` event handler to each checkbox that calls this function, you can also to that with the `dojo/query` and `dijit/registry` module, for example:

```
query("input[type=checkbox]").forEach(function(node) {
    registry.getEnclosingWidget(node).on("change", function(value) {
       toggleCheckboxes(node, value);
    });
});
```

A complete example can be found on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9CpZ6/).

---

But I still recommend using a radiobutton. I think you can actually say this is a bad UI design, a checkbox and a radiobutton have different goals, use them for what they're meant to.